# ClosedXML generating malformatted xlsx

Tags: excel, openxml, malformed, closedxml

Can't seem to output a good file with ClosedXML, when I open the file I'm getting

We found a problem with some content in 'filename.xlsx' Do you want us to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

```
using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
{
    var worksheet = workbook.AddWorksheet("name");
    worksheet.Row(1).Cell(i + 1).SetValue("test");
    worksheet.Row(k + 2).Cell(column.Order + 1).SetValue("test value");
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        workbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return memoryStream.GetBuffer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was either using ToArray() instead of GetBuffer() that fixed the problem. Cheers

```
using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
{
    var worksheet = workbook.AddWorksheet("name");
    worksheet.Row(1).Cell(i + 1).SetValue("test");
    worksheet.Row(k + 2).Cell(column.Order + 1).SetValue("test value");
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        workbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```